# HTML newline using fromCharCode is not working

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I am using `String.fromCharCode` to add new line (or) carriage return to my html text.

It is like,

```
"Ant the other line here..." + String.fromCharCode(13)
```

Jsfiddle is @http://jsfiddle.net/udmfsvfn/

But, no newline characters are added in the page!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a line break in HTML you need to supply `<br>` entity instead of a line break (your `String.fromCharCode(13)` code) since HTML interprets line breaks as usual spaces in text.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that a newline character is not forcing a new line, is that in HTML a newline character doesnt do anything and is ignored.

In order to force text onto a new line, you will need to add the appropriate HTML tag, such as `<BR>` or put your text inside paragraphs `<p>`.

See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udmfsvfn/1/).

Answer (score 0):

`String.fromCharCode(10);`

with CSS

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Here si working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/Nxja/3xtcqdej/1/