# New Line '\n' is not working in Typescript

Tags: css, html, typescript

I am creating a list item in typescript component which will be displayed in the UI. The List items should be displayed in separate lines. So i added new line char \n as below. But still the list items are shown in same line. Below is the code. Any idea why it doesn't work?

[image: UI Display of ul list]

Typescript Code:

```
@Output() excludeDisplay: any = '';
@Output() includeDisplay: any = '';
includeValues: any = '';
excludeValues: any = '';

this.includeValues += this.merId + ',' + this.explodeStatus + '\n';
console.log("include values are "+ this.includeValues);
this.excludeValues += this.merId + ',' + this.explodeStatus + '\n';
console.log("exclude values are "+ this.excludeValues);
this.includeDisplay = this.includeValues;
this.excludeDisplay = this.excludeValues;
```

Html Code:

```
<ul id="excludedUl" required>{{ excludeDisplay }}</ul>
<ul id="includedUl" required>{{ includeDisplay }}</ul>
```

CSS Code:

```
#includedUl {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
}

#excludedUl {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
}
```

Comment: Here is working solution..... https://stackoverflow.com/a/69753810/7320692

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\n` does **not** cause a line break in html.
You'll need to use a `<br/`> or wrap your text in a block element.

```
this.includeValues += this.merId + ',' + this.explodeStatus + '<br/>';
this.excludeValues += this.merId + ',' + this.explodeStatus + '<br/>';
```

Or

```
this.includeValues += '<div>' + this.merId + ',' + this.explodeStatus + '</div>';
this.excludeValues += '<div>' + this.merId + ',' + this.explodeStatus + '</div>';
```

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic and so you've decided to downvote. nice. you're probably doing something different because `<br/>` is the way to do it in html.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will remove the downvote. The n doesn't work for me hoever, and neither does br.......

Comment: What happends to mje is that in the webpage, the <br/> is just displayed like that :) i.e. <br/>......angular preformats it. I'm looking to way to display br as br.....

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic well then, this is not the right thread for you.  `\n` shouldn't work, so that ok, as for the `<br/>', there are other threads for that, i.e.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14963444/angularjs-is-rendering-br-as-text-not-as-a-newline

Answer (score 36):

Need to use fix width:

```
 <div style="width: 500px;white-space: pre-line">{{property}}</div>
```

In typescript use '\n' to add new line.

Comment: No need to specify `width` only `white-space: pre-line` solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If the information is only going to be displayed in the HTML, you can use the CSS property `white-space`. For breaking just the '\n' character then this should work `white-space: pre-line;` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50327465) and for the documentation check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

Answer (score 1):

If you still need the original text with `\n` included for something else, you can always make a call to the [Str.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, to change all `\n` into `<br/>`, so the template works as expected. You could do something like this:

```
this.includeDisplay = this.includeValues.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
```

You can refer to [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#using_global_and_ignore_with_replace).