# How to get line break within string interpolation in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So I'm trying to do something very simple and I'm stuck. I have a `String` variable and within that variable I Wanna set line break so certain part of the text goes to new line.

**What I have tried:**

```
title: string = "My \n Title";
title: string = "My\ Title";
title: string = "My\
Title";
title: string = "My" + "\n" + "Title";
```

I have tried many variations but its just not working. Am I being stupid and missing something very obvious?

Not a duplicate as I have tried the `<br/>` and it has not worked.

**Update:**

The variable is being printed in the browser HTML like so `{{title}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Line '\n' is not working in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743813/new-line-n-is-not-working-in-typescript)

Comment: @LucaKiebel not a duplicate as I have tried the solution in that question and it has not worked.

Comment: @Skywalker what exactly do you expect the newline to **do**?  The `\n` escape definitely includes a newline character in a string. Depending on how the string is actually used, that may or may not be detectable.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to print it ? It matters: console.log or browser HTML render behaves differently.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini its browser HTML.

Comment: @Pointy I wanna move everything after the `\n` onto a new line. Its being used the browser HTML. In my case some move `Title` underneath `My`.

Comment: @Skywalker `{{title}}` is not HTML, it is *text* within HTML. Any HTML inside angularjs interpolation does not get treated as HTML (for security reasons). If you want html, use the `ng-bind-html` attribute. You will have to include the safe html service and inject that into your controller, but that is simple and the documentation is thorough.

Comment: @Skywalker Also, this issue has nothing to do with TypeScript, I will update the question title accordingly

Comment: You should provide a working snippet beacause in html line break IS <br>.
May be you embed your <br> as string and not as JSX ?

Comment: I'm missing a `var`, `let`or `const` at the beginning of your declaration.

Comment: And you shouldn't use double quotes with typescript. You should use single quotes or backquotes

Comment: @rweisse That's a linting preference, not a standard.

Comment: @rweisse That is not true at all.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It's a linting preference. @james-monger what's not true at all?

Comment: @rweisse Saying that one "shouldn't use double quotes" and "should use single quotes" - that's not true. There's no "should" about it - the [TypeScript source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) uses **double quotes**!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @JamesMonger You are right, there is absolutely no reason, nor obligation not to use double quotes, in typescript.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here are two demonstrably working versions...

## White Space

Solution One... if you want newlines to be respected in HTML... (works with the back-tick strings, or with `'My \ntitle'`...

```js
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = `My
title`;
```

```css
h1 {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="example">

</h1>
```

Angular Version:

```
<h1 style="white-space: pre;">{{title}}</h1>
```

## HTML Break

Solution two... you want to use HTML...

```js
document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = 'My<br />title';
```

```html
<h1 id="example">

</h1>
```

Use ng-bind-html if you want to [allow HTML during binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml).

Comment: Close, but OP is using angularjs. Just make it `<h1 style="white-space: pre;">{{title}}</h1>` and this is a working solution for the OP

Comment: Hi @mhodges I wanted to create a short working example... but I'll add a note about that.

Answer (score 43):

In html add style:

```
<div style="white-space: pre-line">{{DialogText}} </div>
```

Use '\n' to add newline in the typescript.

```
this.DialogText = "Hello" + '\n' + "World";
```

Same in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpoxr5linebreak

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a readonly `textarea` element instead of `<div` or `<p>` to keep the format of original string.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<div ng-bind-html="myMsg"></div>

$scope.myMsg =  `Below is the result:  <br>Successful:1,  <br>Failed:2`  // Use backtick
```

Answer (score 0):

Pre-line / pre-wrap didn't work for me, unfortunately.
Found out another solution that worked for me:
For instance, your string variable keeps the next text

```
message = "Some text.\nSome text
```

Then in your html you can do:

```
@for(sentence of message.split("\\n"); track $index) {
    {{ sentence }} <br/>
}
```

In result you'll get all line breaks that your string has

Answer (score -2):

You have done the right thing.
But if you are showing this in a browser, the \n means didley.

You have to do:

```
title: string = "My<br>Title"
```

Now if you are using a fancy front end tool like React, you will have to deal with unsafe HTML in strings...

Comment: This question is tagged as "React", JSX will render "My<br>Title" with proposed code.

Comment: The accepted solution is excellent, because it's purely CSS and has nothing to do with React or Angular.

JSX however will not render this string.
You will have to do this:
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: "My<br>Title"}}/>`