# How to cut the string at every number and create a new line in Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I've angular expression like:

```
<ion-col text-center>{{employeeProfile?.YearOfService}}</ion-col>
```

And this print: 1 years 6 months 10 days

But my desired output will be:

```
1 years
6 months
10 days
```

I'm getting the data from server side as an object and value of

> YearOfService = '1 years 6 months 10 days'

*Those who are proving me another link that already solved this issue, please keep it mind, I'm using Angular 7 not AngularJs. And another thing is that, this is possible in JavaScript with Regular Expression but when I transfer this to Angular Expression it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get line break within string interpolation in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678148/how-to-get-line-break-within-string-interpolation-in-angularjs)

Comment: Not working at all. @PareshLomate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a pipe is better . Also use br tag instead of \n and set innerhtml instead of {{}}

Please find an implementation with pipe below :- 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipe-example-mkqsay

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'custom'
})
export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (value === '') {
      return '';
    }
  return value.replace(/\d+/g, "<br>"+"$&").trim();
  }
}
```

and your html is like

```
<ion-col><div [innerHtml]="employee.Years | custom"></div></ion-col>
```

Comment: This works fine completely. This solution is from pure Angular! Great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace and regex and trim ( used to remove extra space and both side of string )

```
\d+
```

```js
let str = "1 years 6 months 10 days"

console.log(str.replace(/\d+/g, "\n"+"$&").trim())
```

Comment: This works for console print. But when I place the value in {{}} (Angular Expression), it doesn't work!

Comment: This does not solve OP question, the question is about html template

Comment: @AbhijitM.Abhi you can easily call a function inside `{{}}`, read [`Dynamic values inside template`](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp) and [`Calling method in angular`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37385535/calling-method-from-a-angular-2-class-inside-template)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the function in html like

`<div [innerHTML]="{{displayEmployee(employeeProfile)}}> </div>`

and in controller

```
function displayEmployee(profile): String{
    if(profile){
    return profile.YearOfService.replace(/\d+/g, "<br />"+"$&").trim();
    }
    return '';
}
```

By the way I insist on writing properties with small-beginning camelCase

```
yearOfService, not  YearOfService
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Angular Pipe and try to achieve your use case. Please refer docs. https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Code Maniac's answer, you can try this to display in HTML.

```
var val = str.replace(/\d+/g, "<br/>"+"$&").trim(); // use <br/> instead of \n
// and do this:
<div innerHTML = "{{ val }}"></div> // insert as HTML
```

NOTE: I did not test the code.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Code Maniac anwser, use regex to add `\n` yo your string.

Then you can attach a class to the element with the attribute `white-space: pre` ;. This will break it into a new line for you if you're using `\n`.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kgxud6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)