# New line with template literals in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was expecting the `message` to be displayed in two different lines. How do I use `<br/>` tag to split the lines in Typescript?

**TS code**

```
  posts = {
    social: {
      title: "test",
      message: `test message \n
      test message`
    }
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  {{posts.social.message}}
</div>
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mestorf-hp548?file=/src/app/app.component.html). Could anyone please help?

Comment: Doesn't work how?  Given that HTML will typically ignore some white space.  What is not working?

Comment: @Taplar I was expecting message to be displayed in two different lines

Comment: You're building out html.  You either need to use <br> or <p> tags or the like, or style your div with `white-space: pre`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get line break within string interpolation in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678148/how-to-get-line-break-within-string-interpolation-in-angularjs)

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. @yifansong