# Replace \n with <br> tag angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a REST API with `\n` as backslash tags, can angular 6 replace these with `<br>` tags?

Here's my code:

```
{{x.deskripsi}}
```

I try to use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-nl2br-filter), but I have no idea how to use it with binding inside a `{{}}` tag. I tried using

```
<p ng-bind-html="x.deskripsi | nl2br"></p>
```

but it doesn't work. Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an AngularJS 1.x package

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You don't need a library. Simply set the `white-space` property of your tag to `pre-wrap` (or use a `<pre>` tag that should have this style by default)

```js
document.querySelector('#formatted').innerText = 'Lorem\nIpsum';
```

```css
#formatted {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="formatted"></div>
<div>Lorem\nIpsum</div>
```

Comment: @SlimenTN not everything is JS, before making a resource-consuming solution, always try to resolve it with CSS or HTML !

Comment: totally agree with you :)

Comment: Great!  Thank you!

Comment: Great answer, just beware that spaces within your strings will be considered

Comment: Simple and smart!

Answer (score 23):

You can use a pipe for the same:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'replaceLineBreaks'})
export class ReplaceLineBreaks implements PipeTransform {
transform(value: string): string {
      return value.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
   }
}
```

The pipe must be included in your `@NgModule` declarations to be included in the app. To show the HTML in your template you can use the binding `innerHTML`.

```
<p [innerHTML]="x.deskripsi | replaceLineBreaks"></p>
```

Comment: thats work for inner html 
i try use this code `<div [innerHTML]="'<strong>test html content</strong>\nnew line\nthird line' | ReplaceLineBreaks"></div>` its work correctly , but when i try with my binding data is not working, i try using `pure: false` still doesn't work 
any sugest ?

Comment: What type of data you binding on paragraph tag

Comment: I think paragraph tag does not contain any tags inside itself. Please see this link : `https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_p_tag.cfm&hl=en-IN`.

Comment: Not sure but some tags are not supported inside paragraph tags